# Deploying iPhone App with SQLite3

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, deployment, sqlite

I have an iPhone App which contains SQLite3 database(2-3 tables). When I am building it on Simulator it's working fine but while deploying it on iPhone Device it's giving an Pop-Up Message - "Database Error-Failed to Open Database. Hrm"
While in Consol it's showing :

Warning : Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

Need help (As I am new to iPhone Apps and SQLite3)
Code :

```
int result;
result=sqlite3_open("/Users/saggezza/Desktop/TimeTrackerApp/login.db",&database);
```

-(IBAction)button_login
{

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Username varchar,Password varchar,Name Text)",
             NULL, NULL, NULL);





int ret = sqlite3_step(statement);
sqlite3_reset(statement);
if (ret == SQLITE_DONE) 
{
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);

}


const char *sqlStatement1= "select * from login";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement1, -1, &statement,nil);

while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
{

    NSString *uname=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
    NSString *pwd=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]; 

    ename =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]; 



    if ([(textField1.text) isEqualToString:uname] && [(textField2.text) isEqualToString:pwd])
    {



        TimeTrackerAppAppDelegate *timeTracker=(TimeTrackerAppAppDelegate *)[[ UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

         Mainpage *sView = [[Mainpage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Mainpage" bundle:nil ];
         timeTracker.name=ename;

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:sView animated:YES];
        // [self presentModalViewController:sView animated:YES];

        return;
    }


}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is "login.db" stored on your local machine? You must supply the db file in the bundle and then copy it to the documents directory, as described [here] (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Database_Implementation_using_SQLite#Preparing_and_Executing_a_SQL_Statement)

Comment: I have the db file in my App Folder also , supplied to Resources also.
Still not getting. It's working on my Simulator but Showing the error on Device. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not posted any code, its a little difficult to answer your specific problem. But you may find this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Database_Implementation_using_SQLite#Preparing_and_Executing_a_SQL_Statement) helpful. It worked for me on device as well.

Comment: Thanks Sailesh for quick response , I have updates the question. Please have a look.